# why am I getting this format error ‘%c’ expects type ‘int’

Tags: c, syntax, typeerror

why am I getting this error or conflicting types for my function?
where player is just a character I just want to output, to show which player is going next

error

```
tictac.c:94: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’
tictac.c:94: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’
```

code

```
void move(char player)
{
        int place;
        printf("player %c, enter placement: \n", &player);
        scanf("%d", &place);

        if (place == 1)
                board[0][0] = player;
        else if (place == 2)
                board[0][1] = player;
        else if (place == 3)
                board[0][2] = player;

        else if (place == 4)
                board[1][0] = player;
        else if (place == 5)
                board[1][1] = player;
        else if (place == 6)
                board[1][2] = player;

        else if (place == 7)
                board[2][0] = player;
        else if (place == 8)
                board[2][1] = player;
        else if (place == 9)
                board[2][2] = player;
}
```

Comment: Because you're passing a *address* to a *character* format specifier? Maybe??? Admittedly many C compiler errors are a bit cryptic, but this one would be hard pressed to be any clearer. It actually *tells you* what you the format specifier is, what it expects, and what you're actually passing it. Short of automagically *fixing* it for you that is about the best you can hope for.

Comment: Why are you getting an error that tells you exactly why you are getting the error?

Comment: Using `board[(place-1) / 3][(place-1) % 3] = player;` instead of a lot of `if` and `else if` can improve both speed and code beauty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `&player` in `printf`

Change

```
printf("player %c, enter placement: \n", &player);
```

to

```
printf("player %c, enter placement: \n", player);
```

Comment: I thought `player` is `int`, but then I realized it and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply

```
 printf("player %c, enter placement: \n", player);
```

without any address-of `&` operator.